# Polish/Prefix Notation logical expression to Expression Tree and back

Tags: java, constraints, expression-trees, polish-notation

I am looking for a java library that could convert a logical expression wirtten in polish/prefix notation into an abstract syntax tree object and back. This is the syntax used by the [SMT-LIB standard](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/) and [CVC4](http://cvc4.cs.nyu.edu/web/)  and I am trying to create some complex constraints. I don't want to evaluate the expression in any kind of way. For example

```
(and (> Money 500) (= Name "Smith"))
```

should become

```
             and
        /          \
      >             =
    /    \        /    \
  Money 500   Name   "Smith"
```

Additional features required or extendable to achieve:

1. Reading a prefix notation, it must be possible to react on the operator type i.e. some operators are chainable (+ a b c) represents a+b+c. This can easily be handled by using (+ (+ a b) c) . But another operator is (distinct a b c) which means a,b,c pairwise distinct. This would however require a non-binary tree I suppose.
2. Traverse Tree object and change Node content

I don't really know anything about grammars which makes it harder to understand some questions about the topic.

Thanks for every thought and hint!

Here is what I found until now.

**Questions on how to write it yourself:**

Wonderful Answer on how to achieve this kind of conversion in general:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7867104/5451007

[About Trees and Prefix (Polish) Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523957/about-trees-and-prefix-polish-notation)

**Would be great to hear if some of this could help me:**

Might be a similar problem but in c#: [Implementing a prefix notation expression parser using Irony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282917/implementing-a-prefix-notation-expression-parser-using-irony)

Maybe writing a parser and lexer using ANTRL or JavaCC is an option?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590027/5451007

ANTLR:
[Parsing an arithmetic expression and building a tree from it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589951/parsing-an-arithmetic-expression-and-building-a-tree-from-it-in-java)

**Questions concerning problems while programming something equivalent:**
Prefix to expression tree [Build binary expression tree from prefix notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230687/build-binary-expression-tree-from-prefix-notation)

Postfix to expression tree [Converting a Postfix Notation to an ExpressionTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522131/converting-a-postfix-notation-to-an-expressiontree)

[string to abstract syntax tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974236/string-to-abstract-syntax-tree)

**General algorithm ideas:**

Postfix to tree: [Postfix notation to expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423898/postfix-notation-to-expression-tree)

Comment: Well done on your research but unfortunately "I am looking for a java library" makes your question [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: That explains why I could not find anything on the matter here. Sorry. I will try to focus on the additional feature 1) and ask another question hoping for it to be on topic. Will this question get closed automatically?

Comment: @Koronis You might consider [Software Recommendatations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (though I don't know if you'll get an answer there either).