# Insert math equation into binary tree in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I was wondering how inserting an equation such as `5 * 4 + 2 / 3` into a binary tree would work. I have tried doing this on my own however I can only make the tree grow to one side.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i just want to create an expression tree

Comment: It is hard to see what you are doing wrong if you don't show us your code.

Comment: i am not looking for code, just a logical explanation on how to create the tree

Comment: A good place to start is [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297807/polish-prefix-notation-logical-expression-to-expression-tree-and-back, which has a lot of good information links.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in the field, but I wrote basic expression parsers in the past.

1. You will need to `tokenize` your expression. Transform it from a string of characters to a `list` of understandable chunks.
2. You may want to create two structures, one for operators and one for operands. Hint, operators have a priority associated with them.
3. You can apply an algorithm to transform your operators/operands to an `abstract syntax tree` (AST) it's basically just a set of rules, generally used with a queue and a stack.